# how to check if the kernel support for ip alias?

Tags: networking, ip, alias

it surprisingly that I get no explicit results when I googled "kernel ip alias support", and I have looked up the *linux network administrator, 3rd edition*, it says:

> check that you have a /proc/net/ip_alias file; if not, you will have to recompile your kernel

it seems this statement is out-dated, because I don't have the `/proc/net/ip_alias` file, but I can run `sudo ifconfig eth0:0 192.168.0.1` and the output of `sudo ifconfig -a` is:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr f0:de:f1:b8:2b:b9  
          inet addr:10.2.14.102  Bcast:10.2.14.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::f2de:f1ff:feb8:2bb9/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:167089 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:147915 errors:53 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:53
          collisions:78714 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:142585362 (135.9 MiB)  TX bytes:25127121 (23.9 MiB)
          Interrupt:20 Memory:f2500000-f2520000 

eth0:0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr f0:de:f1:b8:2b:b9  
          inet addr:192.168.0.1  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          Interrupt:20 Memory:f2500000-f2520000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find out which module a device is using through these 2 methods. **Note:** Alias interfaces are also called virtual interfaces.

In researching this I do not believe there is an actual kernel module that facilitates virtual interfaces on physical ones, rather it's a function that physical drivers provide.

#### Using the /sys filesystem

If you note which device you're using that has an alias network interface.

```
$ ip addr show eth1
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:a0:cc:79:36:b3 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.6/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global eth1
    inet 192.168.1.254/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global secondary eth1:0
```

Notice the last line, that's my virtual interface, `eth1:0`. Now to find out which kernel module is facilitating it. Taking a look at the `/sys` file system for this device. The path will be the base device that has the alias attached to it, `eth1` in our example.

```
$ ls -l /sys/class/net/eth1/device/driver/
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    0 Jan  8 09:42 0000:00:0a.0 -> ../../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:0a.0
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    0 Jan  8 09:42 0000:00:0b.0 -> ../../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:0b.0
```

So if we `ls -l` follow those paths we'll ultimately get the following driver that's being used by the device.

```
$ ls -l /sys/class/net/eth1/device/driver/0000\:00\:0*/ | grep driver
/sys/class/net/eth1/device/driver/0000:00:0a.0/:
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root     0 Jan  8 09:42 driver -> ../../../bus/pci/drivers/natsemi
/sys/class/net/eth1/device/driver/0000:00:0b.0/:
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root     0 Jan  8 09:43 driver -> ../../../bus/pci/drivers/natsemi
```

So we're using the `natsemi` driver.

```
$ lsmod | grep natsemi
natsemi                32673  0
```

#### lshw

Another method for finding the driver is to use the tool `lshw` and query the network devices.

#### Example

```
$ sudo lshw -C network
...
  *-network:1
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: DP83815 (MacPhyter) Ethernet Controller
       vendor: National Semiconductor Corporation
       physical id: b
       bus info: pci@00:0b.0
       logical name: eth1
       version: 00
       serial: 00:a0:cc:79:36:b3
       size: 100MB/s
       capacity: 100MB/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii fibre 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=natsemi driverversion=1.07+LK1.0.17 duplex=full ip=192.168.1.6 latency=64 link=yes maxlatency=52 mingnt=11 multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100MB/s
       resources: ioport:ec00-ecff iomemory:e8020000-e8020fff irq:12
```

The key lines in this output are these:

```
       bus info: pci@00:0b.0
       logical name: eth1
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=natsemi driverversion=1.07+LK1.0.17 duplex=full ip=192.168.1.6 latency=64 link=yes maxlatency=52 mingnt=11 multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100MB/s
```

If you look at the `configuration:` line you'll notice the `driver=natsemi`. This is that same kernel module.

#### So then where's /proc/net/ip_alias?

This is an older facility in the Linux <2.2 kernels that was removed/depreated in the move to 2.4+ kernels. See the [IP-Aliases Howto for example](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/text/IP-Alias).

*excerpt*

> - IP Alias is standard in kernels 2.0.x and 2.2.x, and available as a
>     compile-time option in 2.4.x (IP Alias has been deprecated in 2.4.x and
>     replaced by a more powerful firewalling mechanism.)

Comment: thanks a lot! but, can you explain why I don't have the  /proc/net/ip_alias file? Since _linux network administrator, 3rd_ may somewhat out-dated, is this file exist in early years, and modern driver modules do not generate this file any longer?

Comment: To my knowledge that's a Linux 2.2 kernel implementation that was removed/deprecated in the 2.4+. See the IP-Alias howto: http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/text/IP-Alias. This is one of the big problems w/ the internet, the old information persists and causes more problems as newer things replace them. Hence why I spend so much time on this site and on my blog 8-)

Comment: @Cifer - I added the details to the A.

Comment: See also [this response](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19862736/2858390) for more details on the deprecation of `ifconfig`.

Comment: @EliasProbst - you're just saying this bit since it's related to the discussion, and the OP used it, right? I made sure not to use `ifconfig` in my A.

Comment: @slm: Sure, it was meant to refer to OP's usage as I didn't want to create a new answer just for this information.

Comment: Does it mean the API has been removed? Does ifconfig now use netlink for IP address configuration or does it use other means?

Comment: Also I don't think the `/sys` section explains how to learn about interface aliasing support. In my opinion if `/proc/net/ip_alias` is absent (which it is with modern kernels), interface aliasing is not available and secondary addresses are handled as a list attached to the same interface as the primary address.

Comment: @PavelŠimerda Take a look at the source to confirm that question. I'd suspect that ifconfig merely makes system calls which had there implementations modified.