# How to make virtual interface ping to a host in the network

Tags: linux, networking, ip, ethernet

I crated a virtual interface as indicated in this [link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/152331/how-can-i-create-a-virtual-ethernet-interface-on-a-machine-without-a-physical-ad).

```
sudo modprobe dummy
sudo ip link set name eth10 dev dummy0
sudo ifconfig eth10 up
sudo ifconfig eth10 192.168.1.150
```

now if I want to make a ping to a host in my network (`ping 192.168.1.133`), then the ping will not work.

I tried to add

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.eth10.forwarding=1
```

But the ping does not work neither.

What should I have to add to make the ping works?

Comment: You say ping doesn't work. What specifically happens when you run ping? What error messages do you get?

Answer (score 1):

Dummy interfaces won't do anything until you make them part of a bridge.

As this is an old question and the asker is not explaining what he actually wants to achieve, and it's impossible to guess this, the question is difficult to answer.

The most straightforward way is to create a bridge on an ethernet interface etc., but then you could have just added the address to the ethernet interface in the first place.

Answer (score -1):

Is it correct, you want to use your `eth10` interface as source interface to make `ping 192.168.1.133`?
If yes, you should use ping command with `-I` option and specify source IP address, or source interface name. Here is an example:

```
ping -I 192.168.1.150 192.168.1.133
```

or

```
ping -I eth10 192.168.1.133
```