# ping from a vlan-device got Destination Host Unreachable

Tags: ping, vlan

I up a vlan device eth0.100 as 192.168.1.100.
The eth0 have address 10.137.16.108

It looks work good when I ping with address.

> *$ ping 10.137.16.108 -I 192.168.1.1*
>
> ```
> PING 10.137.16.108 (10.137.16.108) from 192.168.1.100 : 56(84) bytes of data.
> 64 bytes from 10.137.16.108: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.153 ms
> 64 bytes from 10.137.16.108: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.058 ms
> 64 bytes from 10.137.16.108: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.060 ms
> ^C
> --- 10.137.16.108 ping statistics ---
> 3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 1998ms rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.058/0.090/0.153/0.045 ms
> ```

but if I use device name eth0.100 to do same ping got Destination Host Unreachable.

> *$ ping 10.137.16.108 -I eth0.100*
>
> ```
> PING 10.137.16.108 (10.137.16.108) from 192.168.1.100 eth0.100: 56(84) bytes of data.
> From 192.168.1.100 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
> From 192.168.1.100 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
> From 192.168.1.100 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
> ^C
> --- 10.137.16.108 ping statistics ---
> 5 packets transmitted, 0 received, +3 errors, 100% packet loss, time 4024ms
> ```

I guess that is a issue about arp table

> *$ arp*
>
> ```
>  Address            HWtype  HWaddress   Flags Mask            Iface
>  10.137.16.108        (incomplete)                          eth0.100
> ```

Because I need the vlan device name to use SOL_SOCKET & SO_BINDTODEVICE to send raw socket
Could you help me.

Thanks

Comment: Could you add the output of `ip addr show` and `ip route show`?

Answer (score 1):

Update:

My target is want manipulate traffic control a shared device bandwidth to 10 or more small vm or program. I used vconfig command make virtual interfaces and use tc command.
The dev maked with vconfig looks good when I use address for traffic between host and virtual dev.
But it looks have problem when I use the virtual dev label for traffic by ip protocol.

I find a way to clear my problem.
As this post:
[[How can I create a virtual ethernet interface on a machine without a physical adapter?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/152331/how-can-i-create-a-virtual-ethernet-interface-on-a-machine-without-a-physical-ad])

The solution is use the iproute2 toolkit.
It make a peer virtual interfaces.

```
ip link add veth0 type veth peer name veth1
```

Add address for both virtual device.

```
sudo ip addr add 10.1.1.1/24 dev veth1 && ip set dev veth1 up
sudo ip addr add 10.1.1.2/24 dev veth1 && ip set dev veth2 up
```

Then I can use the dev name as veth2 to ping 10.1.1.1 looks working.

```
ping 10.1.1.1 -I veth2

 PING 10.1.1.1 (10.1.1.1) from 10.1.1.1 veth2: 56(84) bytes of data.
 64 bytes from 10.1.1.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.021 ms
 64 bytes from 10.1.1.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.041 ms
 ^C
 --- 10.1.1.1 ping statistics ---
 5 packets transmitted, 5 received, 0% packet loss, time 3999ms
```

I find the veth kind virtual device have dummy Mac address. May be it is working for ARP and RARP.

```
veth1     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 1a:8d:89:82:da:68  
      inet addr:10.1.1.1  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.255.0
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

veth2     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 2e:11:c9:ad:9c:e7  
      inet addr:10.1.1.1  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.255.0
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

Thank you for your help.

Peter