# RTNETLINK "file exists" error when attempting to create veth interface that was previously a dummy

Tags: linux, networking, interface

**Linux Mint 20.2**

I used this command to create a dummy ethernet interface called veth0:

```
sudo ip link add veth0 type dummy
```

Once finished I removed it with:

```
sudo ip link delete veth0 type dummy
```

The interface was definitely removed. After a reboot I then tried to create a virtual ethernet type interface with:

```
sudo ip link add veth0 type veth
```

But when I do this I get the "file exists" error.

It does allow me to recreate a dummy type interface with the first command again.
Where could it be referencing the interface name to be preventing it from being reused as a virtual ethernet type?

My research has thrown up a lot of similar posts but they all generally reference a problem with physical interfaces not being able to use the ifup command. The fix is to flush the addresses on the interface and make sure is not more that one gateway listed in /etc/network/interfaces. Neither fix applies here. I've found nothing about virtual interface names not being re-usable for different interface types after the previous type is removed.

I realise I could just use a different interface name, but I'd like to clean up this configuration problem and understand what has caused it.

Comment: If it exists, why don't you check? `ip link show dev veth0`. If there's one that means it was created. Whatever happened before or after the reboot, something creates or recreates it. This something might have done this automatically when you created it first or not, but there is not enough information provided in the question to guess what.

Comment: @A.B That's the problem, after deleting it, it does not exist, as confirmed by that command. As said, I can create it again with the same name as a dummy interface, but not as virtual ethernet. Something somewhere must be referencing it.
When I initially created it I used the commands to create and delete it from the top answer in the linked post (I did not create any aliases): https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/152331/how-can-i-create-a-virtual-ethernet-interface-on-a-machine-without-a-physical-ad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is reproducible but is due to choosing a name which interferes with the default choice made by the kernel.

When not specifying a name for the peer interface, the lowest possible interger is appended to `veth` to build the peer name **first**. This happens first, before the main interface itself is created. This can be seen when one specifies a name that can't clash:

```
# ip link add name myveth type veth
# ip link show type veth
17: veth0@myveth: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,M-DOWN> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 2a:93:f8:8e:bc:b6 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
18: myveth@veth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,M-DOWN> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 8a:c3:1d:82:93:a6 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

the peer name is chosen following the usual way: create an interface with the type and next available integer appended to it: `veth`+`0`: `veth0`. The lower index (here 17 versus 18) means it's created first.

Now if one specifies the very same name that the kernel automatically creates first, a clash happens, the specified interface isn't created and the peer interface thus gets deleted. No trace except for a `RTNETLINK answers: File exists`. This can clearly be seen when running in a separate shell `ip link monitor`:

shell 1:

```
$ ip link monitor
```

shell 2:

```
# ip link add name veth0 type veth
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
```

shell 1 again:

```
23: veth0@NONE: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 72:2d:b8:9f:90:6c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
Deleted 23: veth0@NONE: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 72:2d:b8:9f:90:6c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Here `@NONE` means there's no peer link index associated... yet. A `veth` interface does have a peer link index: the other side of the virtual Ethernet wire. It should have resolved the peer link index to the next interface just created with index 24, but then this interface couldn't be created with the name `veth0` because it already existed (even if that's because of its own creation). This triggers the cancellation of the whole operation and the deletion of the ephemeral `veth0` as well as the error message sent back as `File exists`, else leaving no trace of the issue.

Conclusion: to avoid any clash,

- don't specify any name and let the kernel pick them:

  ```
  ip link add type veth
  ```

  getting:

  ```
  24: veth0@veth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,M-DOWN> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default 
      link/ether 2a:93:f8:8e:bc:b6 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
  25: veth1@veth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,M-DOWN> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default 
      link/ether 86:70:54:05:0f:75 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
  ```
- specify a name not following the default naming scheme

  ```
  ip link add name myveth type veth
  ```
- or specify both names, even if they're not the default order they would be created by the kernel in its default naming scheme (peer as `veth0` and main as `veth1`):

  ```
  ip link add name veth0 type veth peer name veth1
  ```
- don't forget `veth` interfaces are most of the time (but not always) useless outside of network namespace environments. The peer interface can get added directly elsewhere if needed:

  ```
  ip netns add othernamespace
  ip link add name veth0 type veth peer netns othernamespace
  ```

  where the peer will also be created as `veth0` without any clash.

  ```
  # ip link show type veth
  27: veth0@if2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
      link/ether 2a:93:f8:8e:bc:b6 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netns othernamespace
  # ip -n othernamespace link show type veth
  2: veth0@if27: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
      link/ether fa:cb:bf:23:fc:a6 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
  ```